# Insert data into 5 tables from a html form

Tags: sql, insert

I have a problem how to place an order for a product, and then insert the order into 5 tables that are connected: ONE-TO-MANY, The tables are so connected that when the customer comes in the room, place an order for a product for e.g. coffee, or water it has to show in the orders page who placed the order, in which room does the customer sits and then the waiter  gets the order into from the status is the product paid or not.
the tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_index1780` (`username`),
  KEY `user_FKIndex1` (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=71 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  KEY `fk_order_room1` (`room_id`),
  KEY `fk_order_user2` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `room` (
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`),
  KEY `fk_room_user1` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `fk_order_has_product_product1` (`product_id`),
  KEY `fk_order_has_product_order1` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type_user` (
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now after I inner join them to place an order for a product nothing's happening.

The query is :

```
SELECT order.order_id,
       user.first_name AS user,
       product.name,
       product.price,
       item_orders.quantity,
       product.price * item_orders.quantity AS sum,
       room.name,
       order.time,
       order.status
FROM user, product, room, `order`, item_orders
WHERE user.user_id = room.user_id
  AND order.room_id = room.room_id
  AND order.order_id = item_orders.order_id
  AND product.product_id = item_orders.product_id
```

***This join is just fine it has only to enter a new join order_id = '$order_id' and that is it.***

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your question and welcome to Stack Overflow! Good that you posted the DDL for your tables, but please show your query, too.

Comment: Ok I posted the query

Comment: Each SQL query you posted use only a single table at a time.

Comment: ok and how can I set this to work I don't have any ideas any more.

Comment: I read he php manual but nothnig , I'm new to php, please help

Comment: Focus on one thing at a time: first, get your queries right. Then, you can ask another question about problems with PHP.

Where is the SQL query where you inner join your tables? Please, post only the _relevant_ SQL code, and not the surrounding PHP code. See also: http://sscce.org/

Comment: the inner join I made is:SELECT order.order_id, user.first_name AS user, product.name, product.price, item_orders.quantity, product.price * item_orders.kolicin AS iznos, prostorija.naziv, narudzba.vrijeme, narudzba.status
   FROM korisnik, proizvod, prostorija, narudzba, stavka_narudzbe
   WHERE korisnik.korisnik_id = prostorija.korisnik_id
   AND narudzba.prostorija_id = prostorija.prostorija_id
   AND narudzba.narudzba_id = stavka_narudzbe.narudzba_id
   AND proizvod.proizvod_id = stavka_narudzbe.proizvod_id

Comment: the inner join I made is:SELECT order.orderid, user.firstname AS user, product.name, product.price, item_orders.quantity, product.price * item orders.quantity AS sum, room.name, order.time, order.status
FROM user, product, room, order, item orders
WHERE user.userid = room.userid
AND order.roomid = room.roomid
AND order.orderid = item_orders.orderid
AND product.productid = itemorders.productid This is the english version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you inserted data in all the tables referenced from your query:

```
INSERT INTO type_user (type_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO user (user_id, type_id, first_name) VALUES (1, 1, 'cappie');
INSERT INTO room (room_id, user_id, name) VALUES (10, 1, 'Room 10');
INSERT INTO `order` (order_id, room_id, user_id, status) VALUES (1 , 10, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO product (product_id, name, price) VALUES (100, 'Product A', 99.99);
INSERT INTO item_orders (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (1, 100, 15);
```

The query you provided (in the comments) will run fine and return (almost) correct **[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5a14/1)** :

```
| ORDER_ID |   USER |      NAME |          PRICE | QUANTITY |               SUM |                          TIME | STATUS |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 | cappie | Product A | 99.98999786377 |       15 | 1499.849967956543 | August, 08 2013 07:03:34+0000 |      3 |
```

*You have a floating point rounding error, but [that's a story for another day](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)*.

Here is the full [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5a14/1).

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, but in status column is the boolean 0 or 1, 0 is for not paid the product, and 1 is for payed product. And how to solve the  floating point rounding error? I hear it for the first time

Comment: For the floating point rounding error should not be a problem because the prices for products are rounded, the prices: 6, 7, 8,12 $.

Comment: The `status` column is declared as `int(11)`. You should have declared it as `BOOLEAN` to document this fact. Anyway, I inserted random values just to show that your query *works fine*.

Comment: For the project it has been said from the professor  that we should not change anything in the database.

Comment: Ok I figured it out that inserting data into user table is not god, so i have tried to use only 2 tables and this is what came out:             
$sql = "INSERT INTO order(status, room_id, weiter_id) VALUES ('$status','$room_id','$weiter_id')";
execute($sql); $new_id = mysql_insert_id();
foreach($quantity as $a => $b) {
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO item_order VALUES ( '$new_id','{$product_id[$a]}','{$quantity[$a]}')";
execute($sql2); But the problem is that it shows duplicates.  if(count(array_unique($produtc_id))<count($product_id)){
 echo "duplicate"
} else {echo "no duplicates"
} but it doesn't work

Comment: This is a topic for another question. Please, ask another question (and feel free to link to this one, to provide background information).

Comment: Ok I link the other question on to another page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142848/inserting-data-into-2-tables-from-a-form-and-removing-duplicates)

Comment: If any of the answers to this question solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks for the advices but I realize now that when I want to show the new orders on orders page the order_id must not be inner joined with the order_id of the item order

Comment: but now when it has to show all the new orders it shows it three times from the same user , tried to remove the duplicates with DISTINCT but it doesn't work any advice?

Comment: You should review your table design before doing anything else. Add `UNIQUE KEY`s where appropriate (`room.name` and `product.name`, for example), and don't add unnecessary foreign keys (an `order` references both an `user` and a `room`, but a `room` also references an `user`; do you need both foreign keys on `order`?).
After that, review your queries. Get them to return correct results (if the underlying data is correct). Don't just add `DISTINCT`.

Comment: When the order is placed on the orders page it has to show the username, name of the product, name of the room ad the quantity

Comment: Exactly my point. Your data model is faulty. Redesign your tables. Remove redundant join paths.

Comment: I can't redesign the tables, it has to be exactly like that. The professor said that the database must be like that how it is. Because if I change anything the professor would not rate it.

Comment: And when i group by order.order_id it doesn't show all the ordered products. It's showing only one product name